# Using @Transactional on service method, which updates multiple repositories

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions

Spring boot, postgres, spring jpa.

Have a service, which is trying to store changes across multiple repositories:

```java
class Service {

    @Transactional
    public void doStuff() {
        repo1.delete(...);
        repo2.saveAll(...);
        repo1.save(...);
    }
}
```

This operation requires to be rolled back if anything fails.

Here I struck into two things:

1. If I add a `throw RuntimeException` somewhere in the middle of that method, all things before it don't get rolled back.
2. In regular flow I get

> Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

My configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManager
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DataConfig {}
```

Also trying to use the `TransactionTemplate` bean with it's `execute` method. Manage to overcome the first issue, but still fail with the second one.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot however your configuration shows you are trying very hard to work around Spring Boot auto-configuration. That being said is this **really** the code you are using or is there some final method lurking around? Also which database are yu using, not by accident MySQL with MyISAM tables (which don't support transactions).

Comment: If by "working arround" you mean the EntityScan and JpaRepositories annotations, I used them to reduce the scan radius to specific packages (if I understood their usage correctly). For the DB - it's postgres. For the code, which I am using - well, I do understand that I'm taking a side road in spring data usage, but this method is a specific case. So yes, it's real and must remain in the same route.

Comment: If the data is persisted and not rolledback your `@Transactional` doesn't work. Also the fact that you get an error whilst committing is telling you something (and please add the **full stacktrace**). So you must be doing something you aren't telling. Also as mentioned is that the real code or psuedo code anomized to partily mimic the actual code? (You wouldn't be the first and last to do that and make a mistake in that leading to nowhere!). ALso you don't need `@EnableTransactionManagement` as Spring Boot takes care of that.

Comment: You were right on the stacktrace part. I lost from my view that I had some jpa validation going on and the reason of `RollbackException` was indeed a validation error. For the `@Transactional`, yes, it wasn't working. And the cause for it was the fact, that testing the flow with `InitializingBean` right from the same bean was a bad idea. Will remove the `TransactionManager`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` this will rollback even if you have an exception in your code

```
class Service {

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void doStuff() {
        repo1.delete(...);
        repo2.saveAll(...);
        repo1.save(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but the thing is - I was throwing `RuntimeException`, which, according to `@Transactional.rollbackFor`, is captured by default. I did manage to find the route of the issue, and it was more related to AOP - `@Transactional` isn't resolved if it's called inside the same bean (and I was using `InitializationBean` interface to test the flow).